# Buggy results using DBSCAN (sklearn) for word clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I am trying to cluster similar looking bigrams using DBSCAN (sklearn) with Levenshtein distance as the distance metric. I need to cluster together similar looking words (Spelling errors) like the following:

Sundar Residency
Sndar Residency
Sundhar Residency

My code:

```
# Distance metric
def lev_metric(x, y):
    i, j = int(x[0]), int(y[0])
    return (editdistance.eval(b1[i], b1[j]))

# Loading data
b1 = debug_data['b1']
b1 = b1.tolist()
X1 = np.arange(len(b1)).reshape(-1, 1)    

# Defining DBSCAN Parameters and clustering
db = DBSCAN(eps = 2, min_samples = 2, metric = lev_metric)
predictions = db.fit_predict(X1)

# Printing results 
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'b1': b1, 'cluster_id': predictions})
tmp.sort_values(by = ['cluster_id'], ascending = True, inplace = True)
print (tmp)
```

The results are mixed. When my eps is 2, which I assume is the Levenshtein distance between any two points in my cluster, all points get clustered in one cluster. While, when it is set to 1, the clustering is better. But, still the Levenshtein distance between any two points is not 1.

[Results with eps == 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abgPG.png)
[Results with eps == 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt37n.png)

Can anyone explain what is happening here? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The results are not buggy, but rather your approach is insufficient. Did you try other metrics? Did you try other clustering approaches? Is DBSCAN even useful for clustering strings? Compare the results with the results of other clustering methods before optimizing a single one. Possibly combining multiple distance measure could improve the results.

Comment: I think it is unlikely that DBSCAN will work for clustering variations of bigrams. [The central idea of DBSCAN is the idea of a core where data points have many nearby neighbours within a specified distance. Two data points belong to the same core if they are connected to each other via data points that have a specified number of neighbours.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) I think it is unlikely that you will have enough variations of each bigram to merit the idea of a core.

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN uses the transitive closure.

Therefore, **the distance of points in one cluster can be *much* larger than epsilon**. It guarantees there exists a *sequence* a,b,c,d,e,f...,x such that every *step* is at most epsilon, but there is no limit on the number of steps.

You could try Leader clustering, but I would rather not use clustering at all, but treat this as a simpler *similarity search* problem - you want to find similar objects, not complex structured groups.